# Component is not a known element despite importing module and including CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

PinchZoom is a node module `ngx-pinch-zoom` that I've installed in my Angular 6 project. It may be worth noting that it's also an ionic 4 project.

In my app.module.ts I have imported the `PinchZoomModule` and included `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` in my schemas.

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { PinchZoomModule } from 'ngx-pinch-zoom';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
  entryComponents: [],
  exports: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    PinchZoomModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

In a page, I have added the proper code to use the PinchZoom functionality:

```
<pinch-zoom>
    <img class="question-image" [src]="myImageUrl" />
</pinch-zoom>
```

However, when I run my app, I get the following error:

```
'pinch-zoom' is not a known element:
1. If 'pinch-zoom' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'pinch-zoom' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("ss="ion-padding no-bottom-padding">
        [ERROR ->]<pinch-zoom>
```

Comment: Why are you reexporting the `PinchZoomComponent` component that should be declared and exported with the `PinchZoomModule` module?

Comment: In which component are you using pinch-zoom?

Comment: Oops, that was from my various attempts to fix the issue, @Edric

I'll remove it from the question.

Comment: @FatemeFazli - In the first ionic page that is shown as the app loads.

Comment: In AppComponent?

Comment: Are you lazy loading any components? You also have to add the `PinchZoomModule` to the component modules that you're lazy loading.

Comment: Well, I'm using ionic's router outlet, so a different component than app.component, however if I try it in app.component, it works @FatemeFazli.

Comment: I think @Edric is onto something here with the lazyloading. Trying it out now.

Comment: you should import ```PinchZoomModule``` only in witch module that is declaring relevant the component that you are using ```<pinch-zoom>``` in it and it will work;)

Comment: That was it, @Edric - thanks so much for your help. Do you want to post it as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: I'm already answer that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which component you currently using pinch-zoom ?

If you are import `PinchZoomModule` you have to import the component you are using that tag also into the module you import `PinchZoomModule`

If you are using `<pinch-zoom>` tag into multiple module consider move it to one share module that import `PinchZoomModule`